# How to compare values in sucessive rows in time series table

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large time series table, in the sense of having many rows for many individual entities.  Each row has a column for the ID for the entity, a date for the first day of a month, then several columns with numeric values.

What I need to do is compare the change in values for columns from one row to the next.  I want to calculate the absolute and percentage change of the values in a row to the values in the previous month's row.

I can make sure that there is a row for every month from the first month of data to the end month for an entity.

In effect I need to gather up the values for a row and the values from the row for the previous month to do calculations for a particular entity.

I am working in SQL Server if there are any SQL specific to it that might help.

What would be an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Does your table have some sort of ID column with a unique increment-by-one sequence, or does it have a date column where each row increase by one day?  Please make your question concrete by showing us sample data.

Comment: There is a date column, that increments the rows by months.  I found another posting that used inner joins to the table itself where I could match the month columns in rows with any offset in months that I needed.